# Label to change in textbox when click edit button asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show data in labels and want when user clicks on edit button labels change into editable text fields. I am using asp.net and c# visual studio 2015. How can I do this please help me.

Comment: it might work to remove the labels from the controls and add at the same position textboxes

Comment: but I want that data also in textbox

Comment: what is stopping you from pulling the data from the labels into some temporal variables and inserting it into the new textboxes?

Comment: actually I would recommend to use textboxes in the first place and set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`. On the button click you could just set it back to false and your fields will become editable still containing the same content

Comment: actually it mess up all things. Textfields size is not adjustable according to text size how can I make textboxes adjustable height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't edit a label use this way : on button click, pass the label1.text on textbox1.text and change the property about read only into false .
Obviously, in the page load, text box read only was set on true.
After, you can pass another time the textbox.text into label.text

Comment: Textfields size is not adjustable according to text size how can I make textboxes adjustable height and width?

Comment: Yes man, you can.
In the property , go to "Text", open the text options and you will found size . Try look the property and option with more attention

Comment: Maybe i haven't understand : why you need adjustable text size and adjustable width height ?

Comment: actually I have to show data from database and may be that can be long details. Label is auto adjustable whereas textbox is not. so when i don't know before what is length of my data how can I set textbox size accordingly

Comment: Indeed you set text mode in multi line ?